# Getting “Uncaught (in promise) Error” from within a catch block

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I'm getting a strange error that I've been wrestling with for almost a day now. It seems my rejected promise is not being caught by my `catch` block. I'm a little new to `es6` `async` and `await`; however, it seems very similar to what I'm used to in C#.

```
Get: async function (request, cancelToken = null) {
console.info('Sending GET', request)
store.commit('global/setLoader', true)
let headers = getAuthTokenHeader()
try {
  var res = await Vue.axios({
    url: baseUrl + request.Url,
    params: request.Params,
    method: 'GET',
    headers
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Failed to GET: ' + error)
    if (typeof error.response !== 'undefined' && typeof error.response.data !== 'undefined' && error.response.data !== null) {
      throw new Error(error.response.data)
    } else {
      throw error
    }
  })
  console.info('Request received', res)
  return res
} finally {
  store.commit('global/setLoader', false)
}
},
```

The error is thrown on the line `if (typeof error.response !== 'undefined' && typeof error.response.data !== 'undefined' && error.response.data !== null) {`

According to https://javascript.info/async-await#error-handling
I should not be receiving this "Ucaught (in promise)" error since I am wrapping the whole asynchronous call in an `await`.

The calling code is also awaiting this code. Here is the call for reference.

```
static async GetPackagingDimensions (input, Id) {
const request = {
  Url: 'api/packing/getPackagingBoxDimensionsByBarCode',
  Params: {
    boxBarcode: input,
    orderId: Id
  }
}
const res = await HttpUtil.Get(request)
return res
```

}

Interesting enough, if I wrap the calling code itself in a `try` `catch`, the error is caught appropriately.

**Why am I not able to catch the rejected promise from within my catch?**

*Quick Edit*
- My `console.log` is also not being called inside the catch, and yet the error seems to be thrown on the following line

[image]

Comment: Because your catch is throwing an error.. ?

Comment: But why is it error in promise? Shouldn't then there be a plain old error console message?

Comment: No because you have marked the function `async`,  it's a promise, and always will be a promise, if you don't catch an error inside your promise, it's a rejected promise, and if unhandled, it's an unhandled promise error.  `Shouldn't then there be a plain old error console message`  No,..

Comment: Looking at your code, your `Get` handler is basically at the end of your promise chain,.  When you get here, you have to handle the error, in Node.js for example, if you don't, future versions of node will even terminate the process.  What I would do, is don't re-throw here, and replace with `console.error` instead. / or if you have some good logging utils, log it..

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to experiment here to see if I can at least log the response. When I removed the *rethrow* logic and simple put a `console.log(error)`, that console never logs. I also placed a `console.log` in the calling code and in there I get an `undefined`.

Comment: Ahh hold on, I'm not returning the `res` object (response) in the catch.

Comment: Also `}).catch(function (error) {`  remove this, and use a proper `catch (e) {}`  Try not mixing Promise callbacks with `async / await`, it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yep, just converted back to normal try catch and am not rethrowing. Now the actual error message is just a string stating *Error: Request failed with status code 400*. What's also more interesting is now the calling code is throwing the `promise` error. What we are basically trying to do here is show the content response from the server in a `toastr`. Our post method works but our get is giving us trouble. I thought I would share some context to help give some transparency on why the simple 400 is not sufficient text

Comment: I figured out the issue. A long way up the call stack the error was being re-thrown yet again. It seems the code would catch the error in multiple places, do something with it, then rethrow. I'm in the middle of refactoring all of this now. Thanks for the hel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try catch do not work like then catch.

```js
try {
  var res = await Vue.axios({
    url: baseUrl + request.Url,
    params: request.Params,
    method: 'GET',
    headers
  })
}
catch(error) {
    console.error('Failed to GET: ' + error)
    if (typeof error.response !== 'undefined' && typeof error.response.data !== 'undefined' && error.response.data !== null) {
      throw new Error(error.response.data)
    } else {
      throw error
    }
}
```

This is how try catch blocks are used in js.
await resolves the promise

if errors are caught while resolving promise then the error is thrown to catch block

Comment: Hello Prajav, I've tried this as well with the same results.

Comment: using catch after try makes no sense in your code. There is no promise involved while catching. BTW if you are running this code on browser, it has low compatibility still.

Comment: Sorry i made a typo while doing it. async / await unlike then catch does not have any error handling so try catch is used to check any errors while resolving promise. If any errors are present then error is thrown

Comment: This is better,  for the OP re-throwing the error will be problematic, as he's attached this to what looks like a get handler,  IOW: The promises will become unahandled,.. If you replace the re-throws with `console.error`, I think this should be what the OP needs..

Comment: Your solution was correct; however, for everyone else's concern, the underlying issue was in code I did not post. In general, this call stack was catching the error on multiple levels and always rethrowing. So no matter what I did in the beginning of the call stack, there was always an error being explicitly thrown somewhere up the chain.

Comment: up the chain? down the **stack** you mean.